# JavaFX application on Mac OS

Tags: java, swing, javafx, desktop-application

I've written app on JavaFX and it's starting successfully on Linux and Windows, but not on mac os. It's showing in processes and there is no exceptions or errors, but GUI not showing.
What special is needed to start such app on mac?

I also tried simple hello world application:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

without no luck ( the same behavior: no GUI is showing, but is showing in processes)

I'm using java 1.7, OS X version: 10.8.5

Comment: Both [tag:javafx] and [tag:swing] work on Mac OS X. Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Your question is off-topic for 2 reasons: it asks about a problem without providing any code to reproduce it, and it asks for opinions.

Comment: In your 1.7 Java you need to put the rt-jfx.jar (in installation dir) onto your build path. Update to Java 1.8, because it includes the JavaFX-Runtime Library.

Comment: Your example works with Java 7 on Mac OS X 10.9.

Comment: Updating to java 8 helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is update to Java 8